# How does eval function work in PHP?

Tags: php, eval

I am trying to figure out how does eval() function works in a simple way. I tried the following code but it doesn't work, instead it shows up a parse error.

```
<?php
    $str = "exit()";
    eval($str);
?>
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: > How to use eval function in PHP ? If you can help it: Not at all. I am only half joking :)

Comment: Sorry the question was wrong :D I am not a native English speaker so i make mistakes.

Comment: No, your question was completely o.k. and fine english. I was referring to the fact that eval() is generally regarded as bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. I got your point, thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

needs a semicolon i think

```
<?php
    $str = "exit();";
    eval($str);
?>
```

From the PHP docs:

> Remember that the string passed must
>   be valid PHP code, including things
>   like terminating statements with a
>   semicolon so the parser doesn't die on
>   the line after the eval()

Comment: Thanx a lot. That tutorial http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/4/0 just confused me a little.

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip - eval'ed code is evaluated dynamically and can evade the garbage collector.

Comment: That's hardly the biggest problem with eval. :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the error: "`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in Command line code(1)`"? If so, that is because you didn't put semicolon at the end of `exit()`.

So try:

```
<?php
    $str = "exit();";
    eval($str);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It needs a semicolon at the end:

and the problem with eval is that it calls the parser from a IL language, thus, the evalued code would be a VSL(very slow language), so, if your website won't be hit by many users at same time, then its no problem, but if you are projecting something big, then I suggest you not use eval, only in really necessary case.

hope it helps.
Joe

Answer (score 0):

`$str = "exit();";` may work.
eval() should not be used, except when really necessary.

Also, try using a function other than exit(), or pass a string as an argument to the exit function. Otherwise, you won't see an output from it.

Comment: I was just trying to follow that tutorial
http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/4/0
It was mentioned there without a semicolon that's why I got confused.